# Mod Rewrite -- apache -- Regular Expression

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to make an folder(and all pages into) on an apache server only accessible by Firefox.

I've write this in the VirtualHost:

```
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}   ^(?!Mozilla.$).*$
            RewriteRule  ^firefox/.+$               index.html [L]
```

But it's not working.
I guess I'm doing a mistake in the regular expression but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I hope you realize that clients can set any user agent string they want.  You can test for Firefox's default user agent string(s), but there's no way to ensure that the client hasn't changed theirs.  For example, Chrome has a [User Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US) extension that allows it to pretend to be any other browser, and other browsers and command-line clients have similar things.

If you still want to do this, then take a look at the [comprehensive list of user agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) to help you choose a regex that will match the many versions of Firefox.  In particular though, look at Internet Explorer and notice that *all* of its user agent strings include the string Mozilla.  For Firefox it looks as though

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  Firefox
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrong.
So know i've try to do the same with:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  (^Firefox.+)$
RewriteRule  ^firefox/.+$               index.html [L]
```

I was suposed to redirct to index every user agent except Firefox.
I guess I doing some mistake in "not equal to Firefox".